# IntelliJ IDEA - how to map remote PYTHONPATH to local environment?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I'm using python remote interpreter in IntelliJ(13.1), and using "composes" modules which are installed on server.

By importing the module like follwing, I can use the module without any problem, but I get warn "No module named composes".

```
import composes
```

And I can't get the auto complete of the module in editor.

Do I need to map the remote PYTHONPATH to local?

If so, please tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some documentation for this:

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/configuring_interpreter.html

I think best way is remote SSH interpreter. Check this out.

Edit: But don't forget. If you choose remote interpreter, you can't use your local modules.

Edit2:

1) Add deployment server from **Tool->Deployment->Configuration**

[image]

2) Add remote interpreter from **File->Settings->Project Interpreter->Add remote** And select the **Deployment Configuration** for FTP connection and can send to server your local files

[image]

3) And now you can upload your files to server from Pycharm. For this **Right click to project folder->Upload to xxx**. If all configuration is okay, now your files will upload to server and you can use `auto-completion` for your local files.

[image]

If it doesn't work, please try **File->Invalidate cache**. And let it delete all cache and download over it again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm using SSH interpreter and my programs go well. But my problem is that the editor put the warn "No module named composes" and I can't get the auto complete of the module.

Comment: What is your client and server OS?

Comment: My client is OSX10.9.4 and the server is CentOS5.10 .

Comment: Okay. Did you set your deployment configuration? If you did, please right click to your py file or project directory in Pycharm and select `upload to xxx`. xxx is your deployment config name.

Comment: Yes, I made a configuration by select `Run -> Edit Configuration -> + -> Python ` and selected `Use specified interpreter -> Remote Python 2.7.8(ssh://myserver:22)`

And I also tried `Upload to xxx` and `Remote Host -> Refresh -> **.py -> Upload here`.

Comment: By doing above settings, I can successfully run my programs on remote python. But it still doesn't show auto complete on my code for the modules which I installed on remote server.

Comment: I tried all the steps you suggested(though some of the process are different in Intellij from Pycharm), but I could’t make `auto-complete` on with the module installed on the server.
But I was impressed with your courteous reply, thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. Can you try this with Pycharm 3.4? You can you use all feature with Pycharm, too.

Comment: Oh, well done. I am happy now. Can you tick the okay for my answer? And maybe upvote. :P :)